# Ontotext GraphDB installation on linux debian (Jessie)

Tags: rdf, triplestore, graphdb

I'm trying to install Ontotext GraphDB free on a debian jessie server.
I've downloaded graphdb-free-8-1-1.deb file but when I'm typing the command

```
sudo deb -i graphdb-free-8-1-1.deb
```

as suggested in the quick start guide (http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/quick-start-guide.html), I get the following message :

```
sudo: deb: command not found
```

It's seems that it has something to do with the /etc/sources.list file. Do I have to insert a line in this file ? how ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That instruction in the quick start guide looks incorrect to me, there's no such thing as a `deb` command AFAIK.

What you need to do to install a .deb file is (from the top of my head) this:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
sudo apt-get install -f
```