# Failed to Install GraphDB on Ubuntu16.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, graphdb

I am trying to install GraphDB free version on my Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 server) but it fails with below error;

```
root@node8:~# sudo dpkg -i graphdb-free-8.8.1.deb 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'graphdb-free' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 77685 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack graphdb-free-8.8.1.deb ...
Unpacking graphdb-free (8.8.1) over (8.8.1) ...
Setting up graphdb-free (8.8.1) ...
Adding shortcut to the menu
/var/lib/dpkg/info/graphdb-free.postinst: 25: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/graphdb-free.postinst: xdg-desktop-menu: not found
dpkg: error processing package graphdb-free (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
graphdb-free
```

Is it supposed to be installed only on desktop version of Ubuntu? Or the free versio of GraphDB can be installed on server edition too?

This solution does not work either as it fails on first command as above and also fails on second command.

[Ontotext GraphDB installation on linux debian (Jessie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042717/ontotext-graphdb-installation-on-linux-debian-jessie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the native application relies on GUI the installation fails. You can use the distribution package instead and run it in server mode:
http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/quick-start-guide.html#run-graphdb-as-a-stand-alone-server